# WooCommerce: Display price of selected variation within [product_page id="xx"]

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, price, product-variations

I successfully replaced the price range with the price of the selected variation within variable product types. I used the following within my child theme's function.php to achieve this.

```
function iconic_variable_price_format( $price, $product ) {

    $prefix = sprintf('%s ', __('Starting', 'iconic'));

    $min_price_regular = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
    $min_price_sale    = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    $max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
    $min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );

    $price = ( $min_price_sale == $min_price_regular ) ?
        wc_price( $min_price_regular ) :
        '<del>' . wc_price( $min_price_regular ) . '</del>' . '<ins>' . wc_price( $min_price_sale ) . '</ins>';

    return ( $min_price == $max_price ) ?
        $price :
        sprintf('%s%s', $prefix, $price);

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'iconic_variable_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'iconic_variable_price_format', 10, 2 );
```

Everything fine to this point. Anyhow, if I insert the entire product page with shortcode `[product_page id="xx"]` The default price is shown above and the price of the selected variation is shown at the bottom right next to the add-to-cart button. Is there a seperate template file for product pages being inserted via shortcode? I'd like to have everything displayed the same way as it is displayed on the product page itself.

Comment: I have tested your code and for me it works the same way on single product pages or on a custom page with `[product_page id="xx"]` shortcode…

Comment: Hi again!
I've done research and I'm afraid that this issue is caused by many themes out there. The project in which this occured was Divi

Comment: Hi again too … I really don't like DIVI with woocommerce… I get the same thing on versions 3.2.x and 3.3.x … So you should better contact Divi support as they are reactive and nice…

Comment: I've got version 3.3.3 of WooCommerce running where this issue occures

Comment: So on Storefront theme with 3.3.3 it works perfectly the same way on single product pages and on normal pages with a shortcode. So this is related to DIVI (or others customizations you have done or third party plugins)…

Comment: probably, I got WooCommerce Germanized running as well... but I'm convinced this is caused by the theme. I'll keep this thread updated as soon as I get response from DIVI authors. Thanks so far!